# Geoserver API REST for adding and deleting REST service access rules (ACL)

Tags: geoserver

I need some help with Geoserver rules, and I'll explain what's going on. So, the thing is, we got this file called `{GEOSERVER_HOME}/data_dir/security/rest.properties`  that we want to tweak. The goal is to set up user accounts, roles, and workspaces for new clients who buy our products. We want them to publish their own stuff on Geoserver through our portal but keep 'em restricted to their workspace.

Now, here's where it gets tricky. We tried adding some rules to the file, but the order is messing us up.

Thank you in advice

It follows all the attempts we made to get a better understanding.

```
# DEFAULT SETTINGS:
/**;POST,DELETE,PUT=ADMIN
/**;GET=ADMIN
```

These rules grant the ADMIN role unrestricted access to all possible requests of the REST API.

```
# AFTER A POST REQUEST:
# Url:
<geoserver url>/rest/security/acl/rest
# Body: (json)
{ "/**/workspaces/client_role/**:GET": "ADMIN,client_role" }
# File (rest.properties):
/**;POST,DELETE,PUT=ADMIN
/**/workspaces/client_role/**;GET=client_role
/**;GET=ADMIN
```

These rule should grant the client_role role access to all possible GET requests of the REST API relative to his own workspace. However, as a trade-off, the rules also revoke access for the `ADMIN` role to the client_role workspace.

So I edit the rule into:

```
/**/workspaces/client_role/**;GET=ADMIN,client_role
```

And it worked.

Then I set the rule for POST, PUT and DELTE requests whit an other POST request:

```
# Url:
<geoserver url>/rest/security/acl/rest
# Body: (json)
{  "/**/workspaces/client_role/**:POST,PUT,DELETE": "ADMIN,client_role" }
# File (rest.properties):
/**;POST,DELETE,PUT=ADMIN
/**/workspaces/client_role/**;GET=ADMIN,client_role
/**;GET=ADMIN
/**/workspaces/client_role/**;POST,PUT,DELETE=ADMIN,client_role
```

The file functions correctly for GET requests but fails to handle POST, PUT, and DELETE requests as intended. It seems that the processing stops at the first rule. For example, when I send a POST request with a user assigned the "client_role" role, the service responds with a `403 Forbidden error`.

But if I manually edit the file into:

```
/**/workspaces/client_role/**;GET=ADMIN,client_role
/**;GET=ADMIN
/**/workspaces/client_role/**;POST,PUT,DELETE=ADMIN,client_role
/**;POST,DELETE,PUT=ADMIN
```

It works as it should.

Instead, as mentioned before, if I change the rules for the client_role workspace as it follows:

```
/**/workspaces/client_role/**;GET=client_role
/**;GET=ADMIN
/**/workspaces/client_role/**;POST,PUT,DELETE=client_role
/**;POST,DELETE,PUT=ADMIN
```

The ADMIN role have no longer the permissions to access to the client_role workspace.

There appears to be an issue with the pooling or analysis of these rules, and It seems that after a POST request, the entire file is rewritten.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has already been agreed that it is a bug on the developers mailing list